# In what order should I watch Durarara?

Tags: durarara

I only watched the first season of Durarara a few years ago. Since then, [Durarara x2 Shou](https://myanimelist.net/anime/23199/Durararax2_Shou), [Durarara x2 Ten](https://myanimelist.net/anime/27831/Durararax2_Ten) and [Durarara x2 Ketsu](https://myanimelist.net/anime/27833/Durararax2_Ketsu) were aired, as well as some specials.

If I want to watch the whole Durarara series from the beginning, in what order should I watch it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to watch it from the beginning. Watch it according to this order.

1. Durarara Episode 1-12
2. Special 1: Heaven's Vengeance
3. Episode 13-24
4. Special 2: World at Peace
5. Durarara x2 Shou 1-4
6. x2 Shou Special: Watashi no Kokoro wa Nabe Moyou
7. Shou 5-12
8. Durarara x2 Ten EP-1
9. x2 Ten Special: Onoroke Chakapoko
10. x2 Ten - Remaining
11. Durarara x2 Ketsu

Sources:

[List of Durarara Episodes on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Durarara!!_episodes)

[List of Durarara x2 Episodes on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Durarara!!%C3%972_episodes)

[MyAnimeList](https://myanimelist.net/anime/23199/Durarara)

[TheTVDB](http://thetvdb.com/?tab=seasonall&id=133341&lid=7)

Answer (score 0):

In the order you listed them, I don't know about the specials but the order is season one then the durarara X2 which has three parts(shou, ten, ketsu)

Answer (score 0):

There's also a special for Ketsu called Dufufufu!! that takes place in between episodes 7 and 8. Aside from that, that list is totally correct. If you're still hungry for more like me, well then it's on to the light novels.